# extjs renderer not executed

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, renderer

Im using the modern toolkit with extjs 6.5.1. 
I want to use the renderer property in a grid cell to use html. The renderer simply returns `'<a>...</a>'` but when I use this it will encode the html code so that the cell shows `'<a>...</a>'` instead of a link.
Regarding to the answers on this thread I will need a cell property with "encodeHtml" turned to false but as soon as I add a cell property the renderer wont get executed anymore (Even when I use EncodeHtml) and shows the data like there was no renderer property.
Why cant I use the renderer property anymore?

Heres my code:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    renderer: function(value, record, dataIndex, cell, column) {
        console.log('hello world');
        return '<a>...</a>';
    },
    width: 30,
    text: '...',
    cell: {
        xtype: 'textcell',
        encodeHtml: false
    }
}
```

[What it looks like without encodeHtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxTQy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is because you specify

```
cell: {
    xtype: 'textcell'
}
```

in the first place. Just remove it, and your `renderer` can return HTML. This should work:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    renderer: function(value, record, dataIndex, cell, column) {
        console.log('hello world');
        return '<a>...</a>';
    },
    width: 30,
    text: '...'
}
```

At least id does in my application, where I use `renderer`s returning html to generate special formatting.

If you need to specify the `cell` property, because of something you didn't show in your code, use the default `cell` `xtype` instead: `gridcell`.

Comment: I need the cell property for the encodeHtml property which is required becuase otherwise the renderer will return plain text showing `<a>...</a>` in the cell instead of a link. As I'm using Sencha Architect I cant change the xtype to gridcell.

Comment: I was able to change the xtype manually to gridcell by manipulating the code. Thanks for the help!